# search function javascript submit

Tags: javascript, search

So i am trying to make a function that searches trough an xml file, my results are given but the page is refreshed and keeps loading. I figured this was because of a submit but i used return false and i still have the same problem. Can anyone help me?

Below is my code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(XMLname)
{
var xmlDoc;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlDoc=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlDoc.open("GET",XMLname,false);
  xmlDoc.send("");
  return xmlDoc.responseXML;
  }
else if (ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"))
  {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.load(XMLname);
  return xmlDoc;
  }
alert("Error loading document!");
return null;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="oForm" name="oForm" onsubmit="search(); return false">
<input type="text" name="name" id="txt_name" size="30" maxlength="70">
<input type="submit" value="klik" onclick="search()"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

function search(){
name = document.oForm.name.value.toLowerCase();
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("data.xml");
var nodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("article");
for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    var titleNode = nodeList[i];

    if(titleNode.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.toLowerCase() == name){
        document.write("<div style='width:450px;'>")
        document.write("<p>"+titleNode.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</p>");
        document.write("<p>"+titleNode.getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</p>");
        document.write("<p>"+titleNode.getElementsByTagName("urltext")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</p>");
        document.write("</div>")
    }
}
}
</script>
```

I would like to repeat that i do get results i only lose my layout and the page keeps loading. I made this for safari/safari mobile so i would apreciate it if someone could present a solution. I cant use any serversided scripts either since i need to be able to cache this offline so i figure it has to be javascript.

Ty in advance

*EDIT*

```
    <input type="text" name="name" id="txt_name" size="30" maxlength="70">
<input type="button" value="klik" onclick="search();"/>

name = GetElementById("txt_name").value.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Why do you need a submit button for that? You could simply use a regular button. And I don't see where you're returning false to the submit request?

Comment: @Martin i used a regular button too and it still gives the same issue

Comment: Then don't use a form altogether, but use a button, give the text input an id and just use GetElementById("id").value for the content of the input...

Comment: Load your page into firefox, look in the console. There is bound to be an error. Using onsubmit and returning false works unless there is an error in the code or the processing. Remove the code from the submit button

Comment: @Martin so you mean like this? (edit above)

Comment: name = document.getElementById("txt_name").value.toLowerCase();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the xml processing code works, do it like this - document.write WIPES the page
PS: Firefox MAY not work as expected due to linefeeds in the XML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(XMLname) {
  var xmlDoc;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlDoc=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlDoc.open("GET",XMLname,false);
    xmlDoc.send("");
    return xmlDoc.responseXML;
  }
  else if (ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.load(XMLname);
    return xmlDoc;
  }
  alert("Error loading document!");
  return null;
}
var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("data.xml");
var nodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("article");
function search(theForm) {
  var name = theForm.myname.value.toLowerCase();
  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    var titleNode = nodeList[i];
    if (titleNode.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.toLowerCase() == name) {
      html += "<div style='width:450px;'>";
      html += "<p>"+titleNode.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</p>";
      html += "<p>"+titleNode.getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</p>";
      html += "<p>"+titleNode.getElementsByTagName("urltext")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"</p>";
      html+= "</div>";
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=html
    }
  }
  return false; // cancel the submit
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="oForm" name="oForm" onsubmit="return search(this)">
<input type="text" name="myname" id="txt_name" size="30" maxlength="70">
<input type="submit" value="klik"/>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I never knew a document.write wipes a page o.O thank you very much. As u can see I have a lot to learn.

Comment: The document.write wipes the page after load. You can write inline if you must, but innerHTML or DOM manipulation is better

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<input type="submit" value="klik" onclick="return search()"/>
```

and in the search method:

```
function search() {
   .....

   return false;
}
```

EDIT 1:
you can also add an event for the form itself:

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
```

(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp)

EDIT 2:
This works for me:

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="alert('yo');"/>
</form>
```

Comment: well ive tried all that (done it again) and doesn't work for me... I still get to a page with no layout (i got the results) and the page keeps loading :(

Comment: Poor suggestion. If you want to use the form's events, use the form's submit event and leave the button's event alone!

Comment: in your code you call the search method twice, once when the submit button is clicked and then when the onsubmit event is fired on the form.
have you tried it **exactly** as in the code i added in my 2nd edit?

Comment: theres also the difference, i trigger a whole function with my code... Maybe there is something wrong in there?

Comment: or as @mplungjan said: <form onsubmit="search(); return false;">

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer yes, ive tried every return false suggestion including yours

Comment: it sounds like you're doing something wrong, but try the suggestion @martin made, don't use a form, and get the text input by its id.

Comment: the biggest problem was document.write after load